# SQL query output not as expected

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL. Thanks for your patience.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    population. "District.Name",
    sum(population. "Number") AS "Total Pop",
    sum(unemployment. "Number") AS "Total Unemployment"
FROM
    population
    FULL JOIN unemployment ON population. "District.Code" = unemployment. "District Code"
WHERE
    population. "Year" = 2017
GROUP BY
    population. "District.Name",
    population. "Number",
    unemployment. "Number"
ORDER BY
    sum(unemployment. "Number") ASC
```

;

However, the output generated is as shown in screenshot attached:

[image: SQL output].

I'd like to get the total pop/ total unemployment for each district rather than how it appears currently.
I'm also trying to figure out what's causing the split within the district names. I've tried various combinations but not getting the desired result yet.
Any suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure, you dont want to GROUP BY `population. "Number"` and `unemployment. "Number"`

Comment: That WHERE clause makes the FULL OUTER JOIN to return LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Save some typing; `ORDER BY "Total Unemployment"`

Comment: Please provide some sample data and all the columns you have in the schema

Comment: Tip of today: Don't use dots in object names. Simply just too confusing... Swith to e.g. underscore.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help, as wold a tag for a specific database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - you don't need to add `population. "Number", unemployment. "Number"` columns in group by as you are using aggregation on these columns

```
SELECT
    population. "District.Name",
    sum(population. "Number") AS "Total Pop",
    sum(unemployment. "Number") AS "Total Unemployment"
FROM
    population
    FULL JOIN unemployment ON population. "District.Code" = unemployment. "District Code"
WHERE
    population. "Year" = 2017
GROUP BY
    population. "District.Name",
ORDER BY
    sum(unemployment. "Number")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes- group by is where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

you need to group by District.Name only. Since you have grouped by Population and Unemployment they are showing unique rows also.

Hope this works!

```
SELECT
population. "District.Name",
sum(population. "Number") AS "Total Pop",
sum(unemployment. "Number") AS "Total Unemployment"
FROM
population FULL JOIN unemployment ON population. "District.Code" = unemployment. "District Code"
WHERE
population. "Year" = 2017
GROUP BY
population. "District.Name",
ORDER BY
sum(unemployment. "Number") ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`FULL JOIN` is almost never needed, and certainly not for a query with a `WHERE` clause.  I suspect `INNER JOIN` is quite sufficient.

However you are getting multiple rows.  This suggests that aggregating *after* the `JOIN` is going to overcount something.  Aggregate *before* doing the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p."District.Name", p."Total Pop",
       u."Total Unemployment",
       (p."Total Pop" * 1.0 / u."Total Unemployment") as ratio
FROM (SELECT p."District.Name", SUM(p."Number") AS "Total Pop"
      FROM population p
      WHERE p."Year" = 2017
      GROUP BY p."District.Name"
     ) p INNER JOIN
     (SELECT u."District.Name", SUM(u."Number") AS "Total Unemployment"
      FROM unemployment u
      GROUP BY u."District.Name"
     ) u
     ON p."District.Code" = u."District Code"
ORDER BY u."Total Unemployment" ASC;
```

I suspect your numbers will still not be what you expect, because you are filtering on the year only for the population.  I suspect both numbers should have a similar filter.  If this is the case, then *ask another question*.  Provide sample data and desired results.

In terms of style:

- Don't put spaces in column aliases.
- Absolutely don't put periods, unless you have no choice.
- That is, create column and table aliases that do not need delimiters -- much easier to write and read queries.
- Use simple table aliases.